# How to put availabe disk space into filename?

Tags: disk, cron, disk-usage, sftp

I have a SFTP user only and I want it to be able to see available space.

I want to make a `cron` that runs each 30 minutes, to delete the old file and put the new file to show free disk space.

I could just put `df -h > df.txt`, but I don't want to do that. I want an empty file, with the filename like: `3.1G.available`, and then in the shell script delete `*.available` and create the new file - which is run by cron.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start out with the `df` command, using the `-h` option to give use the size in human readable format (gigabytes in this case)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       226G  2.4G  213G   2% /
udev            1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           691M  324K  690M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/shm
```

Now let's use `grep` to narrow the output of that command down to only the partition we care about - `sda1`

```
$ df -h | grep 'sda1'
/dev/sda1       226G  2.4G  213G   2% /
```

Looks good. Let's continue narrowing it down to only the 'Available' column, using `awk`

```
$ df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk '{print $4}'
213G
```

That will work. Now we'll wrap our command in backticks, so the output is returned to the shell. Then we'll use the `touch` command to create an empty file using the output from the command we've built, along with the string '.available'

```
$ touch `df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk '{print $4}'`.available
$ ls
213G.available
```

There you go!

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
touch `df -h --output='avail' / | tail -1`.available
```